# Projectile motion - Net Work and speed

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work, projectile

I have proved this statement in multiple ways. Yet my intuitive proof goes against the mathematical proof: one must be wrong!

##### **Statement**

> In a projectile motion with no drag, the magnitude of the projectile speed at height $h\leq h_{max}$ of its trajectory depends on $v_i$, $g$, $h$ but not on $\theta$

- **Intuitive Proof**
  Imagine two projectiles launched at the same speed from the same initial position yet with different angles: one is launched straight up, and one is launched such that $h = h_{max}$. Since the one launched straight ahead reaches the height $h$ faster, the deceleration by gravity will be less, hence the magnitude of the final speed will be higher than the other projectile. Hence the statement is wrong.
- **Mathematical Proof**
  The statement can be proved from the net-work theorem, assuming we only have conservative forces.
  $W^{net}_{a->b}=\Delta K=-\Delta U=-mgh$
  $\Delta K/m = (v_f^2-v_i^2)/2 = -gh$
  $v_f = \sqrt{v_i^2 - 2 g h}$
- **Numerical Proof**
  I have also proved the statement using the known equations $x(t)$, $y(t)$. I do not want to bore you: in summary we find $t_f : y(t_f)=h$ and then v(t_f) and we calculate its magnitude. Then we compare this result with the previous result -- and wolfram alpha asserts that they are the same (with values $g$, $h$, $v_i$ such that $h\leq h_{max}$ can be reached). Also, experiments on [fisicalab](https://www.fisicalab.com/en/section/parabolic-motion) confirm the statement.

##### **Questions**

1. Is the statement true? = Are the mathematical/numerical proofs correct?
2. If they are? Why is the intuitive proof wrong? Is it because we assume there is no drag? Is it because speed is two-dimensional and intuition does not account for the speed magnitude being calculated with the square of its components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intuitive proof is proven wrong by the mathematical proofs. So it is clear that the intuitive proof doesn't stand up to mathematical scrutiny, but I think that you are looking for an intuitive reason why the intuitive proof fails.

The key error is here

> Since the one launched straight ahead reaches the height h faster, the deceleration by gravity will be less, hence the magnitude of the final speed will be higher than the other projectile

The mistake you are making in this proof is that you are confusing a change in velocity with a change in speed. Velocity is a vector quantity so it has a magnitude and a direction. The magnitude is speed.

So, a constant force means a constant rate of change in velocity. So it is true that the projectile launched straight up will get to a given height faster than one launched diagonally. And because gravity is a constant force the straight-up projectile will have a smaller change in velocity. But it is not true that the change in speed will be less.

Consider a fixed change in velocity and several different initial velocity vectors. The first is aligned directly with the change. That vector will have an increase in speed. An initial velocity aligned directly against the change will have a decrease in speed. An initial velocity aligned nearly perpendicular to the change will just turn with no change in speed. So the same change in velocity can lead to positive, negative, or zero change in speed.

So, the intuitive proof fails because it correctly identifies that the straight-up projectile has a smaller change in velocity, but it simply assumes that a smaller change in velocity implies a smaller change in speed. That assumption is not correct, and in fact is wrong enough that exactly the opposite conclusion is correct.